# conflict in jquery files on the same page

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a design for a shopping portal,where i am creating design as HTML pages.Every thing is working fine till now. but now i got a requirement to add a carousel to my page. when i include it, carousel works fine but all other images in the page get diappeared.
when i tried to locate the error i found jquery file(jquery-1.10.2.min.js) conflicting it. When i remove this jquery file , the page works fine except for the carousel which does not get displayed and if i include this jquery file carousel works fine and all other images get disappeared.

Any help in this case will be appreciated.

My code is as:

```
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Home page
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Default Description"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Magento, Varien, E-commerce"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      try{
        if (!window.CloudFlare) {
          var CloudFlare=[{
            verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{
              cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok2v=1613a3a185/"}
            ,atok:"36a1387ad6e467e69406d7f097f16792",petok:"39bc36baccf2ce30ae4417d7b96f86df2716dc2f-1417606940-86400",zone:"template-help.com",rocket:"0",apps:{"abetterbrowser":{"ie":"7"}
                                                                                                                                                                 ,"ga_key":{"ua":"UA-7078796-5","ga_bs":"2"}
                                                                                                                                                                }}
                         ];
          !function(a,b){
            a=document.createElement("script"),b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],a.async=!0,a.src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok2v=919620257c/cloudflare.min.js",b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}()}}catch(e){};
      //]]>
    </script>
    <link rel="icon" href="skin/images/opilis.bmp" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="skin/frontend/default/theme315k/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <!-- <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes%7CLobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
    <link href="fontsapis/cssfont4.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var BLANK_URL = 'js/blank.html';
var BLANK_IMG = 'js/spacer.gif';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
<a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
<img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." />
</a>
</div>
<style>
body {
min-width: 960px !important;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/photoswipe.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/extra_style.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/superfish.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/camera.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/widgets.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cmsmart/ajaxsearch/ajaxsearch.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cmsmart/ajaxsearch/jquery.multiselect.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cmsmart/ajaxsearch/assets/prettify.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ecommerceteam/cloud-zoom.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/catalogsale.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/hitch/ajaxlogin/ajaxlogin.css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css" media="print"/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery_noconflict.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype/prototype.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ccard.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype/validation.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/builder.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/effects.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/controls.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/slider.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/js.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/form.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mage/translate.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mage/cookies.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cmsmart/jquery/ajaxcart/cmsmart-ajaxcart.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/product.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/configurable.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar/calendar.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendar/calendar-setup.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cmsmart/ajaxsearch/ajaxsearch.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cmsmart/ajaxsearch/jquery-ul.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cmsmart/ajaxsearch/prettify.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cmsmart/ajaxsearch/jquery.multiselect.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ecommerceteam/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/bootstrap.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/jquery.touchSwipe.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/jquery.unveil.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/cherry-fixed-parallax.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/tm-stick-up.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/superfish.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/scripts.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/jquery-ui.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/bundle.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/carousel.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/hitch/ajaxlogin/jquery-ui-1-10-4.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/hitch/ajaxlogin/ajaxlogin.js">  </script>


    <!--carousel-->

        <script src="carousel/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

        <!-- /.CDN -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="carousel/js/jquery.anoslide.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .carousel { position:relative; min-height: 20px; height:auto !important; height: 20px;  background:url(images/loader.gif) center center no-repeat; }
            .carousel .next,
            .carousel .prev { display:none; width:56px; height:56px; position:absolute; bottom:20px; left:50%; margin-top:-28px; z-index:9999; cursor:pointer; }
            .carousel .prev { margin-left:-60px; background:url(carousel/images/prev.png) 0 0 no-repeat;  }
            .carousel .next { margin-right:-60px;  background:url(carousel/images/next.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
            .carousel li { display:none; }
            .carousel li img { width:100%; height:auto; }
            .paging { position:absolute; z-index:9998; }
            .paging > a { display:block; cursor:pointer; width:40px; height:40px; float:left; background:url(carousel/images/dots.png) 0px -40px no-repeat; }
            .paging > a:hover,
            .paging > a.current { background:url(carousel/images/dots.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;  }
            .badge { display:block; width:104px; height:104px; background:url(carousel/images/badge.png) 0 0 no-repeat; z-index:9000; position:absolute; top:-3px; left:-3px; }
            img {
-webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;    
}
            /* Figure */
        </style>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
           <script>
              document.createElement('header');
              document.createElement('nav');
              document.createElement('section');
              document.createElement('article');
              document.createElement('aside');
              document.createElement('footer');
              document.createElement('figure');
           </script>
        <![endif]-->

      <!--carousel-->


  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    Mage.Cookies.path     = '';
    Mage.Cookies.domain   = '';
    //]]>
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cmsmart/ajaxcart/css/default.css" type="text/css"/>
  <style type="text/css">
    #ajaxcartmsg{
      background:#FFFFFF!important;
      border:5px solid #DDDDDD!important;
    }
    div#ajaxcart{
      margin-left:0px;
      width:320px;
      background:#FFFFFF;
      border:0px solid #DDDDDD!important;
      box-shadow:0 0 3px #DDDDDD}

  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var baseUrlAjax = '##';
  var cartlinkclass = 'ul.links a.top-link-cart';
  var ajaxConfirmMsgDelItem = 'Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?';
  var ajaxConfirmMsgEmpty = 'Empty cart?';
  //]]  
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var Translator = new Translate([]);
    //]]>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-7078796-5']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script');
      ga.type = 'text/javascript';
      ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    }
    )();

    (function(b){
      (function(a){"__CF"in b&&"DJS"in b.__CF?b.__CF.DJS.push(a):"addEventListener"in b?b.addEventListener("load",a,!1):b.attachEvent("onload",a)}
      )(function(){"FB"in b&&"Event"in FB&&"subscribe"in FB.Event&&(FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create",function(a){
        _gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","like",a])}
                                                                                      ),FB.Event.subscribe("edge.remove",function(a){
        _gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","unlike",a])}
                   ),FB.Event.subscribe("message.send",function(a){
                     _gaq.push(["_trackSocial","facebook","send",a])}
                                       ));"twttr"in b&&"events"in twttr&&"bind"in twttr.events&&twttr.events.bind("tweet",function(a){
                     if(a){
                       var b;
                       if(a.target&&a.target.nodeName=="IFRAME")a:{
                         if(a=a.target.src){
                           a=a.split("#")[0].match(/[^?=&]+=([^&]*)?/g);
                           b=0;for(var c;c=a[b];++b)if(c.indexOf("url")===0){
                             b=unescape(c.split("=")[1]);
                             break a}
                         }b=void 0}
                       _gaq.push(["_trackSocial","twitter","tweet",b])}
                   })}
       )}
    )(window);
    /* ]]> */
  </script>

  </head>
  <body class="ps-static  cms-index-index cms-home">
    <div class="wrapper ps-static en-lang-class">  


                  <script type="text/javascript">
                    var baseUrl = '#';
                    var minchar = 3;
                    var t_request = 500                      
                  </script>


        <div class="index-container">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="index_block">
                  <div class="header_slider">
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/camera.js">
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                      /* index slider */
                      jQuery(function(){
                        jQuery('#camera_wrap').camera({
                          alignmen: 'topCenter',
                          height: '51.264%',
                          minHeight: '50px',
                          loader : false,
                          pagination: false,
                          fx: 'simpleFade',
                          navigationHover:false,
                          thumbnails: false,
                          playPause: false 
                        }
                                                     );
                      }
                            );

                    </script>
                    <div class="fluid_container">
                      <div class="camera_wrap camera_orange_skin" id="camera_wrap">
                        <div data-src="skin/images/slider/MainSlide7.png">
                        </div>


                      </div>
                      <div class="clear">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

                <!--carousel start-->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.carousel ul').anoSlide(
                {
                    items: 1,
                    speed: 500,
                    prev: 'a.prev[data-prev-mixed]',
                    next: 'a.next[data-next-mixed]',
                    lazy: true
                })
        </script>


                <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="carousel" data-mixed>
                <a class="prev" data-prev></a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="wrap"><figure><img data-src="carousel/images/slides/thumbnails/1.jpg"  /></figure></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="wrap"><figure><img data-src="carousel/images/slides/thumbnails/2.jpg" /></figure></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="wrap"><figure><img data-src="carousel/images/slides/thumbnails/3.jpg"/></figure></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="wrap"><figure><img data-src="carousel/images/slides/thumbnails/4.jpg" /></figure></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="wrap"><figure><img data-src="carousel/images/slides/thumbnails/5.jpg"/></figure></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="wrap"><figure><img data-src="carousel/images/slides/thumbnails/6.jpg"  /></figure></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="wrap"><figure><img data-src="carousel/images/slides/thumbnails/7.jpg" /></figure></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a class="next" data-next></a>

            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.carousel[data-mixed] ul').anoSlide(
            {
                items: 5,
                speed: 500,
                prev: 'a.prev[data-prev]',
                next: 'a.next[data-next]',
                lazy: true,
                delay: 100
            })
        </script>




        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.carousel.captions ul').anoSlide(
            {
                items: 1,
                speed: 500,
                prev: 'a.prev[data-prev-caption]',
                next: 'a.next[data-next-caption]',
                lazy: true,
                onStart: function(ui)
                {
                    ui.slide.element.find('.caption').remove();
                },
                onEnd: function(ui)
                {
                    var content = ui.slide.element.data('caption');

                    var caption = $('<div/>').addClass('caption').css(
                    {
                        position:           'absolute', 
                        background:         'rgb(0,0,0)',
                        color:              'rgb(255,255,255)',
                        textShadow:         'rgb(0,0,0) -1px -1px',
                        opacity:            0.5,
                        top:                -100,
                        left:               50,
                        padding:            20,
                        webkitBorderRadius: 5,
                        mozBorderRadius:    5,
                        borderRadius:       5
                    }).html(content);

                    caption.appendTo(ui.slide.element).animate(
                    {
                        top:50
                    });
                }
            })
        </script>

                        <!--carousel end-->


        </div>

          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe the carousel you are using has a no-conflict version or option, have you checked the docs? I don't know what kind of carousel you are using since there are a LOT of javascripts used.

Comment: @chrki any suggestions for me?

Comment: why are you loading jQuery twice? It should only be loaded once and before all plugins and dependent code. Also you clearly have a `noConflict` file so use according to docs

Answer (score 0):

You have jQuery loading twice in your provided code sample. The 1.10 version is also loading after all the other jQuery libraries.

It may be that your carousel is not compatible with jQuery v1.11, and that's why it's not working for you.

First, take out the v1.10 jQuery link. Second, either get an update of the carousel so it works with v1.11 or find another carousel library to use. There really are so many out there that do work fine.